# Bind content with range to an key

Tags: automation, autoit

I want to bind some variable textcontent to an specific key (example on key p)

For example:

First press on p: "**hannes1**"

second press on p: "**hannes2**"

third press on p: "**hannes3**"

And so on. Thanks for any help.

Comment: are those several fixed strings (`alpha`,  `beta`, `gamma`) or just one fixed string with a counter( `hannes<n>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question if you want a fixed string `hannes` with a counter or "the next string from a list", so I added both options (available via `p` and `P`

```
; Global $aVars[3] = ["hannes1", "hannes2", "hannes3"]
HotKeySet("p", "_SendVarArray")
HotKeySet("P", "_sendvarCount")

While True
    Sleep(25)
WEnd

Func _SendVarArray() ; write strings from an array; rotating
    Local $aVars[3] = ["One", "Two", "Three"] ; define EITHER here as Local OR in main program as Global
    Local Static $x = UBound($aVars) - 1 ; initial value for next line to be changed as start value '0'
    $x = Mod($x + 1, UBound($aVars))
    Send($aVars[$x])
EndFunc   ;==>_SendVarArray

Func _SendVarCount()
    Local Static $x = 0 ;  'Static' to remember value with next execution
    $x += 1
    Send("hannes" & $x)
EndFunc   ;==>_SendVarCount
```

NOTE: an ordinary letter is a bad choice for a hotkey, because if a string you `send()` contains that letter, it will activate the hotkey function too (I kept it anyway, leaving it to you to find a better key(combination)).

The advantage of `HotKeySet()` is that your program can do other things while waiting for the hotkey being pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Change the ConsoleWrite to Send if you want to send the keys to any application.

```
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $hDLL = DllOpen("user32.dll")
Local $counter = 0

While 1
    If _IsPressed("50", $hDLL) Then
        ; Wait until key is released.
        While _IsPressed("50", $hDLL)
            Sleep(25)
        WEnd
        ConsoleWrite("Hannes" & $counter & @CRLF)
        $counter +=1
    ElseIf _IsPressed("1B", $hDLL) Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "_IsPressed", "The Esc Key was pressed, therefore we will close the application.")
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
    Sleep(25)
WEnd

DllClose($hDLL)
```